# Using for loop with grep function R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to write a for loop that clusters some genes. Here is my code:

```
for (i in 1:10) {

  cluster <- names(pheat.cut.map[grep(i, pheat.cut.map)])

  print(cluster)

  assign(paste("cluster", i, sep=""), cluster)

  cat("\n")

}
```

It works perfectly for everything except 1. The loop counts genes that in cluster 1 and cluster 10. Any suggestions??

Comment: You will probably get more useful answers if you prove a minimal reproducible example. Your code cannot be run by others. And you do not provide any indication what kind of object `pheat.cut.map` is.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 cluster <- names(pheat.cut.map[grep(paste0(i, '$'), pheat.cut.map)])
```

This generate a regular expression that means `1` with anything at the end. That exludes de 10 value when you are looking for 1

You can also use `paste0('^', i, '$')` to mean 'nothing before an nothing after' to avoid grep values as 11, 111, 12 when you are looking for 1

```
grep(paste0(1, '$'), 1:11)
[1] 1 11

grep(paste0('^', 1, '$'), 1:11)
[1] 1
```